# Count one-to-one relationship in grails

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm

I have a problem doing a query. That I want to do is access with a query to the data in my "String code" in MyDomainA through a query from MyDomainB. The relationship between the tables is unidirectional one to one.

Is possible use a gorm way to do this??

Domain A:

```
class LicenceType {

    String code
    String description
    Double price

    static constraints = {
    }

}
```

TABLE DOMAIN A

```
code description
A    this is A
B    this is B
C    this is C
```

Domain B: (have the unidirectional relationship)

```
class VoiceUser {

LicenceType licenceType

String username
String email
String nameID
```

}

TABLE DOMAIN B

```
User 
1    
2    
3    
4
```

That I want to do is know how many users have the same code(code is a column of DomainA and both tables have a unidirectional relationship as I indicated before).

This is that I'm trying to do that is wrong...
Controller:

```
        def resulta = VoiceUser.executeQuery('SELECT a.code, COUNT(b.nameID) FROM VoiceUser AS b INNER JOIN b.licenceType AS a GROUP BY a.code')

def resultCount = resulta[0]
```

This is some example result that I hope...

```
Users with code A = 2
Users with code B = 2
Users with code C = o
```

Comment: Why do you need to go through `MyDomainB` if the query looks like it only uses `MyDomainA`?

Comment: I updtaded the question. Because in MyDomainB I have the users and in MyDomainA I have the codes, Both tables have a unidirectional relationship. But I'm not be able to do correctly the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to do a `group by` on the `code` and a `count()` on the `user`. You can do this using either HQL or a criteria query.

## HQL

Here's an example in HQL:

```
VoiceUser.executeQuery('SELECT licence.code, COUNT(user) FROM VoiceUser AS user INNER JOIN user.licenceType AS licence GROUP BY licence.code')
```

If you're familiar with SQL, most of this should make sense right away. An important difference is the syntax for joining domain classes. HQL deals with domain classes, not tables.

## Criteria query

And here's the equivalent criteria query.

```
VoiceUser.withCriteria {
    projections {        
        licenceType {
            groupProperty('code')
        }

        count('id')
    }
}
```

## Alternative queries

The queries shown above return a `List<List>` like this:

```
[
    ['A', 2], 
    ['B', 2], 
    ['C', 0]
]
```

If you provide a `LicenceType` (or its code) as input to the query, then you can get the count for just that `LicenceType`. For instance, here are examples which retrieve the user count for licence code 'A'.

### HQL

```
def result = VoiceUser.executeQuery('SELECT COUNT(user) FROM VoiceUser AS user INNER JOIN user.licenceType AS licence WHERE licence.code = :code', [code: 'A'])[0]
```

### Criteria query

```
def result = VoiceUser.createCriteria().get {
    licenceType {
        eq('code', 'A')
    }

    projections {        
        count('id')
    }
}
```

## Additional resources

I've got a [series of articles](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-select-clause/) which explain HQL, criteria, and where queries in detail; such as how to use projections and joins. Feel free to check them out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and to the link. I'm trying to do your code and don't works well. I'm getting the object Ljava.lang.Object;@180b129 and not the total users that have the code 'A' for example. That I want to show is how many users have code A, how many users have code B... I think that is only match with A,B,C...

Comment: My example aims to return a List that looks like this: `[['A', 2], ['B', 2], ['C', 0]]`. If it's not working, then I can only help if you show the actual domain class code and query you're running, rather than a sanitized example.

Comment: I update with the domain and the query. That I only want is get users that match with code=A