# How can I do a countby in a one-to-one relationship in grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, one-to-one

I'm some hours trying to do a countby in a unidirectional one-to-one relationship and I can´t. Someone can help me?? I'm trying to do with gorm, but I can accept another code that works.

This is my Domain A.

```
class LicenceType {

    String code //this column have the values A,B,C..
}
```

DomainB

```
Class Users{
LicenceType licenceType
}
```

This is that I'm trying to do but don't works:

```
def typeA = Users.countByLicenceTypeCode("A")

[typeACount: typeA]
```

The result that I want to get is something like this example:

Licence A: 5 users
Licence B: 3 users

Comment: something very similar asked just earlier today http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34043166/count-one-to-one-relationship-in-grails